# Can't run script inside postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql, production-environment

Assume we need to run second postgres instance in our production environment. First of them (`postgres-one`) already running and has few databases & data in them. Now I want to update my `docker-compose.yaml` file and add configuration for the second (`postgres-two`). Moreover I have to grab some databases info from `postgres-one` and copy it to `postgres-two`. Here how I'm trying to achieve this:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
postgres-two:
    image: postgres:12.5
    depends_on:
      postgres-one:
        condition: service_started
    ...
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    command: bash -c "chmod +x /usr/local/bin/init.sh && /usr/local/bin/init.sh"
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres-two/init-db/init.sh:/usr/local/bin/init.sh
```

**init.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# allows you to skip the password prompt for pg_dump
echo "postgres-one:5432:dbname1_one:dbuser1_one:dbpass1_one" > ~/.pgpass
echo "postgres-one:5432:dbname2_one:dbuser2_one:dbpass2_one" >> ~/.pgpass

chmod 600 ~/.pgpass

# gets the data from external database & copies it to internal
pg_dump -h postgres-one -U dbuser1_one dbname1_one | psql -h localhost -U dbuser1_two -d dbname1_two
pg_dump -h postgres-one -U dbuser2_one dbname2_one| psql -h localhost -U dbuser2_two -d dbname2_two
```

But when I run this I get the error:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I already tried it w/o `-h localhost` before, it gave me this as I remember:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory         Is the server running locally and accepting         connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

If I add `find /var/run/postgresql/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432` in the beginning of the `init.sh` it'll show nothing. So, as I understand I can't proceed further with `psql` because postgres server is not running at the moment. And of course I can't run it with `postgres / pg_ctl` commands because they can't be executed by root:

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.

And of course docker containers run as the root user by default, and if I change the user it also give me errors such as:

> chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/bin/init.sh': Operation not permitted

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe I can get the dumps and apply them in other ways.. somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I solved the problem by placing the `init.sh` script into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. But then I also had an access issue with `pg_dump` because for some reason `.pgpass` didn't work in my case. For those, who will face the same problem, I fixed it with `PGPASSWORD` env like that:

```
PGPASSWORD="dbpass1_one" pg_dump -h postgres-one -U dbuser1_one dbname1_one | psql -h localhost -U dbuser1_two -d dbname1_two
```

Answer (score 0):

I think server is failing to start because of volume mapping,
You can refer to this yml,
https://github.com/khezen/compose-postgres/blob/master/docker-compose.yml